# How to sort by timestamp streaks SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, datediff

Say I have the following tables (simplified version of what I'm working with):

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
  id INTEGER,
  title VARCHAR(255),
  text TEXT,
  author_id INTEGER,
  created_at TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE authors (
  id INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  email VARCHAR(255)
);
```

What I want to do is retrieve only the authors but order them by number of one-week streaks. That is, number of consecutive weeks an author published a post. The time a post has been made is stored in the posts created_at column

What I'm having the most difficulty with is understanding how to calculate the difference in time between posts across rows. I’m using MySQL

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using ?

Comment: Please provide (1) sample data (2) desired results (3) as database tag.

Comment: @Avi I’m using MySQL

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry I’ll update with an MCVE shortly

Comment: @bobanthony No rush. ;-)

Comment: Something like this will do: `SELECT authors.name, posts.title FROM posts AS posts LEFT JOIN posts AS post2 ON post2.author_id=posts.author_id AND post2.created_at<posts.created_at LEFT JOIN authors AS authors ON posts.author_id=authors.id WHERE post2.id IS NULL GROUP BY authors.name ORDER BY posts.created_at;`

Answer (score 0):

Without window functions it's a bit hard to do in MySql 5.7

But here's an experiment test snippet that uses variables :

**Sample data:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `posts`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `authors`;

CREATE TABLE `authors` (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  email VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title VARCHAR(255),
  `text` TEXT,
  author_id INTEGER,
  created_at TIMESTAMP,
  CONSTRAINT fk_posts_author_id FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES `authors`(id)
);

insert into `authors` (name, email) values
('john doe', 'john.doe@home.net'),
('jane sheppard', 'jane.sheppard@home.net');

insert into `posts` (author_id, created_at, title, `text`) values
(1, '2019-02-07', 'When', 'bla'),
(1, '2019-02-09', 'I', 'bla2'),
(1, '2019-02-14', 'Start', 'bla3'),
(1, '2019-02-19', 'looking', 'bla4'),
(1, '2019-03-10', '...', 'bla5'),
(2, '2019-02-01', 'I', 'blah1'),
(2, '2019-02-05', 'frighten', 'blah2'),
(2, '2019-02-19', 'even', 'blah3'),
(2, '2019-03-20', 'myself', 'blah4');
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT q3.ConcurrentWeeks, q3.StartWeekDate, a.*
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) as ConcurrentWeeks, MIN(WkDt) as StartWeekDate, author_id
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT q1.WkDt, q1.Total
        , case 
          when @author = author_id and @yr = yr and @wk = wk-1 then @rnk
          else @rnk := @rnk + 1
          end as rnk
        , @author := author_id as author_id
        , @yr := yr as yr
        , @wk := wk as wk
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 
             author_id, YEAR(created_at) as yr, WEEK(created_at) as wk
             , COUNT(*) AS Total
             , COALESCE(MIN(STR_TO_DATE(concat(YEAR(created_at),' monday ',WEEK(created_at)),'%X %W %V')), MIN(CAST(created_at AS DATE))) AS WkDt
            FROM `posts` p
            GROUP BY author_id, YEAR(created_at), WEEK(created_at)
            ORDER BY author_id, yr, wk
        ) q1
        CROSS JOIN (select @author := null, @yr := null, @wk := null, @rnk := 0) init
    ) q2
    GROUP BY author_id, rnk
    HAVING ConcurrentWeeks > 1
) q3
LEFT JOIN `authors` a ON a.id = q3.author_id
ORDER BY ConcurrentWeeks DESC, StartWeekDate ASC
```

**Result:**

```
ConcurrentWeeks StartWeekDate   id  name            email
--------------- -------------   --  -------------   ----------------------
3               2019-02-04      1   john doe        john.doe@home.net
2               2019-01-28      2   jane sheppard   jane.sheppard@home.net
```